# Unity: Players respawns with disabled controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this code to respawn my player when he hits his enemy. Everything works fine, but when the players spawn, he's uncontrolable. For some reason the Player clone has the controller script unchecked in the inspector.

Anyone have any idea as to why that happens & how to solve it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
```

public class RedEnemy : MonoBehaviour {

`GameObject spawnPoint;
GameObject Player;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    spawnPoint = GameObject.Find ("spawnPoint");
    Player = GameObject.Find ("Player");

}

//collider
void  OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other  ){

    if (other.tag == "Player") {
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        GameObject Clone;
        Clone = Instantiate(Player, spawnPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

}`

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroying the player, you can simply reset their stats and move them.

Alternatively, you can enable the controller when the new player is spawned. Using whatever the name of your controller script is, you can do this:

```
Clone.GetComponent<Controller>().enabled = true;
```

You might also want to consider further your design. Having each enemy hold a reference to the spawn point and the player is a bit silly, and those `Find` operations will be taxing is you're spawning a large number of enemies. Ideally, since you only have one player and lots of enemies, you'd have the code for controlling the player in the player class, not the enemy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply, I'll try out all your tips!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea to instantiate a `Gameobject` that isn't a prefab. You should only instantate prefabs and your code is instantiating an instance of a `GameObject` (sorry for the redundancy).

As your instance is being destroyed, that may result in an unexpected behaviour when trying to call `Instantiate` on it instead of on the prefab, like the one you are experiencing.

You should make a prefab of your player, then make your `Player` variable public and set it to the prefab of the Player in the inspector.